# is using constants for language file a good idea from the performance point of view?

Tags: php

im trying to implement a language file. 
im tossing between gettext and constants.
i noticed that several OS projects use constants.
are there any performance dissadvantages to using many constants?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have many things to translate then using constants won't be a big deal. If you have a lot of things to translate then remembering a huge list of constants will get annoying. With gettext there is no remembering.

Comment: maybe it's misunderstanding of gettext on my side but the problem i have with gettext is that if i want to refactor the statements in the future, i will have to update/create new po/mo files which will probably create more headaches than constants, which I can add move edit one by one anytime. please correct me, if im wrong